# How do I close a stream after a file transfer over WCF?

Tags: c#, wcf, file-transfer

I am writing a web service that transfers a file over tcp using a binary, streaming connection.

I have some testing code set up but when I try to read the same file twice I get an exception, that the file is already open (by the previous call).

How can I close the file AFTER the transfer was complete? I tried a using block, but it didn't work.

Comment: Perhaps there are some events like TransferCompleted, Completed, etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's covered here: http://devdump.wordpress.com/2008/12/07/disposing-return-values/

Furthermore, you probably want to open the streams using a constructor like [this one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tyhc0kft.aspx), as follows:

```
var myStream = new FileStream("blah.txt", FileMode.Read, FileAccess.Read);
```

That way, multiple clients can call your method simultaneously.